# How to remember the organization a user is logged in for? Switching between organizations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, ruby-on-rails-4, authentication

**Background:**

- `User` and `Organization` have a `many-to-many` relationship through `Relationship`. So a user can be part of multiple organizations.
- But a user can only be logged in for 1 organization.
- Therefore the user has a screen where he can switch between the organizations he belongs to.
- Also, `user` has a default organization, which is the organization the user initially logs in for. This is implemented using a `has-one through` relationship.

**How to know/remember which organization a user is currently logged in for?**

Now I'm a bit in a pickle how to implement how the app should know/remember which organization a user is currently logged in for. I see three options and am hoping for advice which should work best:

1. An **additional column in the `User` db** that stores the id of the `organization` (or `relationship`?) for which the user currently is logged in. A helper method `logged_in_for` could then find the organization based on the value in that column and return the organization the user is logged in for. Implementation using a db column also enables validation so that a user can't set the organization it is logged in for to an organization it is not even part of.
2. Use a **cookie**: `session[:logged_in_for]` that defines/sets the organization the user is currently logged in for. However, 1) I have doubts whether this is secure (not sure why), 2) I think the first option facilitates validation better, 3) I also don't think this would work in combination with the log in "remember me" option?
3. Implement an **additional `has-one through` relationship** that defines the organization a user is logged in for. This is basically an extension of the first option that adds a relationship. Since I already have so many relationships I don't prefer this option. Or is there no way around this addition for the first option?

Is the first option indeed an effective way to know/remember which organization a user is currently logged in for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on which experience you're looking to create for the end user. In your cases:

1. This will allow remembering of organization between logins, which in your application, can be useful or complete non-sense. If indeed it's useful to remember an organization (i.e, the logistics of user choosing an organization after login is non-frequent), then this could create a better user experience.
2. `session` is secure, and you can use it like a hash and it would not collide with other features in your app (unless you use the same key). This case is suited for your application when user should always choose an organization after login, and thus it should be session based.

Ref: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html

3. Like you mentioned, this is non-ideal, as you already know.

Comment: Thanks, it sounds like `session` is the way to go. What happens to `session` in the following use case though: 1) user logs in with "remember me" checked; 2) `session[:logged_in_for]` hash gets set; 3) user closes browser while still being logged in; 4) user opens browser and website again, which doesn't require login because of "remember me" option. Wouldn't then `session[:logged_in_for]` be `nil` since this gets destroyed upon closing the browser?

Comment: 1) `session` is not affected as the "remember me" option will use cookies (exact implementation varies); 2) You will have access to `session[:logged_in_for]` as long as the browser session is live; 3) The `session` will be erased but the `cookies` will persist, allowing user to come back without log in if "remember me" is selected; 4) You're correct, the `session[:logged_in_for]` will be nil. Now, it depends on to what degree you want to remember the organization for the user. You can use `cookies` for machine dependent, store in db across machines. However,  remember `cookies` is not secure.

Answer (score 2):

You can store the information in [sessions hash](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#what-are-sessions-questionmark), but not use cookie store, instead use [Active Record store](https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this difference between cookie and Active Record store!